# getting unknown result with a trivial forall

Tags: c++, z3

I am using th z3 C++ API. if I create this simple false expression:

```
z3::expr x = C->int_const("x");
z3::expr p = z3::forall(x, x==0);
```

and try to solve, I get an unknown outcome. I am not an expert of strategies and tactics, but I am sure that z3 can solve this, if I use the right tactic.

I also tried

```
z3::expr p = !z3::forall(x, x==0);
```

with, of course, the same runknown esult.

Comment: See the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988298/what-are-the-limits-of-reasoning-in-quantified-arithmetic-in-smt

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with z3, but from a general C++ perspective, wouldn't `x==0` evaluate first, *i.e.* wouldn't your call be equivalent to `implies(x, 1)`? From a quick search it seems you may have to construct each piece of the statement as a z3 object, for example:

```
Z3_ast consequent = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, x, 0);
Z3_ast theorem = Z3_mk_implies(ctx, x, consequent);
```

But the above is not correct, either. I believe the parameters `x` and `0` themselves have to be instances of `Z3_ast` that encapsulate the statement you mean (as opposed to their interpolated values or references).

Comment: That's not true, it is a valid z3 construct. If I substitute the forall with an exists, it solves to true, as one expects. maybe you got confused because i wrote the expression badly, sorry. I updated it now.

Comment: Hm, it's probable that indeed I'm mistaken. But are you saying that z3 overloads C++'s `==` operator, then, produce a statement out of `x==0`, instead of evaluating it?

Comment: exactly, the C++ apis do that ;) it overrides pretty much everything